# Using a Superglobal as a Default Function Parameter in PHP

Tags: php, global-variables, default, user-defined-functions, default-parameters

There are multiple ways I can conceive for achieving the following functionality; however I am hoping for a super elegant solution. Can I use a PHP superglobal variable as the default value for a user defined function parameter?

Example:

```
function test1($foo=$_SERVER['PATH']) {
   echo $foo;
}
```

The above code spits out an error. Like I said I know that I can achieve the same thing using the following code (but the above code is more attractive):

```
function test2($foo) {
   if (!isset($foo)) $foo = $_SERVER['PATH'];
   echo $foo;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I believe the first solution wouldn't work because at script evaluation time (similar to compilation for interpreted languages), the `$_SERVER['PATH']` value is not yet defined.

Comment: That sounds plausible; The error that the PHP engine is spitting out is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in M:\test.php on line 2" Do you think that that error agrees with your explanation?

Comment: I would say it does. A variable (a runtime element) would probably not make sense in a static context (a "compile" time element).

Comment: Thanks Lior, that is a sensible answer to the question and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend passing in the variable, but if you want to use a global one, you can do this

```
function test2() {
    global $foo;
    ...
}
```

at the top of your function and set the value somewhere else, or go with your second idea - but you need to specify a default value in the function parameter to make it optional.

```
function test2($foo='') {
   if (empty($foo)) $foo = $_SERVER['PATH'];
   echo $foo;
}
```

Another way to work with variables from outside your function is to pass them in by reference. This passes in a reference to the original variable, not a copy, so any changes you make inside the function will affect the original variable value outside of the scope of the function as well.

```
$foo = 'bar';
function test2(&$foo) {
   echo $foo;  // this will output "bar"
}
```